# What is the best way to use secondary URL when primary URL fails using HTTPRequest

Tags: c#

```
public string Post(string url,Request request)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            string response = string.Empty;
            **WebResponse myHttpWebResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();**
                //what is the best way to use a secondary url if WebResponse is null..
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                response = sr.ReadToEnd();

            }
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can make the method return NULL in case WebReponse is Null or Exception happens. Now from the Caller code, call post method with Primary Url and check the return value. If Null then pass secondary.

Comment: to summarize what I said, your Post method is wrapper over native http post and should be Single Purpose Method. It shouldnt cater to Primary/Secondary Url - which is part of Robustness.

Comment: Agreeing to what @PrateekShrivastava said and adding, you should understand why your primary URL is failing(could be a temporary issue) so you should have Retry mechanism in your caller code, if Retries also fail(Permanent issue with Primary URL) you should go for FallbackURL for a certain period of time so that other calls are also not made to Primary URL. May be you should search for CircuitBreaker and try implement.